# D3 Javascript - these lines won't move

Tags: javascript, html, animation, d3.js

Working on a D3 project, and have successfully animated some circles moving randomly.  I'd like to have a line drawn between them and some point (which I've done), but the lines don't seem to update with the circles!

I was under the impression that because of D3's data binding, the UI would always reflect the data, so all I need to do is modify the underlying data!

See my issue below (I apologize for the long code post).

```js
function play() {
 run = !run;
}

var run = false;

var canvas = d3.select('html')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', screen.width)
  .attr('height', screen.height);

var text = canvas.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", 300)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr('id', 'fps');
 
var start = Date.now(),
 frames = 0;

function agent(_x, _y, _vx, _vy, _color) {
 this.x = _x;
 this.y = _y;
 this.vx = _vx;
 this.vy = _vy;
 this.color = _color;
 this.lines = [];
}

function line(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) {
 this.x1 = _x1;
 this.y1 = _y1;
 this.x2 = _x2;
 this.y2 = _y2;
}

var data = d3.range(3).map(function() {
 return new agent(
  (Math.random()-0.5)*5,
  (Math.random()-0.5)*5,
  0,
  0,
  'rgb(255, 0, 213)');
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.lines.push(new line(d.x, d.y, 0, 0));
});

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([-5, 5])
 .range([0, screen.width/3]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([-5, 5])
 .range([0, screen.height/3]);

var circles = canvas.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
   return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
   return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
   return d.color;
  });

var lines = canvas.selectAll('line')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr('x1', function(d) {
   return x(d.lines[0].x1);
  })
  .attr('y1', function(d) {
   return y(d.lines[0].y1);
  })
  .attr('x2', function(d) {
   return x(d.lines[0].x2);
  })
  .attr('y2', function(d) {
   return y(d.lines[0].y2);
  })
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1);

//initializes circles at center to begin
render();

d3.timer(function() {
 //Update FPS
 var now = Date.now(), duration = now - start;
 text.text(~~(++frames * 1000 / duration));
 if (duration >= 1000) frames = 0, start = now;

 if (run) {
  rendezvous();
  render();
 }
});

function render() {
 circles.attr('transform', function(d) {
  return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
 }).attr('fill', function(d) {
  return d.color;
 });
    //Transform the line here???
}


function rendezvous() {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.vx += (Math.random()-0.5)*0.5;
  d.vy += (Math.random()-0.5)*0.5;
  d.x += d.vx;
  d.y += d.vy;

  d.lines[0].x1 = d.x;
  d.lines[0].y1 = d.y;
  d.lines[0].x2 = 0;
  d.lines[0].y2 = 0;
 });
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: rgb(39, 40, 34);
 position: absolute;
}

h1 {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 color: white;
}

#fps {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 fill: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body id = "body">
  <h1>Swarm Demo: </h1>
  <button type="button"onclick = "play();">Play/Pause</button>
 </body>
 <script src="js/rendezvous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the *best* solution, but given your code as it is right now, this is a *possible* solution:

```
if (run) {
    lines.attr('x1', function(d) {
            return +(d3.select(this).attr("x1")) + d.vx;
        })
        .attr('y1', function(d) {
            return +(d3.select(this).attr("y1")) + d.vy;
        })
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
function play() {
 run = !run;
}

var run = false;

var canvas = d3.select('html')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', screen.width)
  .attr('height', screen.height);

var text = canvas.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", 300)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr('id', 'fps');
 
var start = Date.now(),
 frames = 0;

function agent(_x, _y, _vx, _vy, _color) {
 this.x = _x;
 this.y = _y;
 this.vx = _vx;
 this.vy = _vy;
 this.color = _color;
 this.lines = [];
}

function line(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2) {
 this.x1 = _x1;
 this.y1 = _y1;
 this.x2 = _x2;
 this.y2 = _y2;
}

var data = d3.range(3).map(function() {
 return new agent(
  (Math.random()-0.5)*5,
  (Math.random()-0.5)*5,
  0,
  0,
  'rgb(255, 0, 213)');
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.lines.push(new line(d.x, d.y, 0, 0));
});

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([-5, 5])
 .range([0, screen.width/3]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
 .domain([-5, 5])
 .range([0, screen.height/3]);

var circles = canvas.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
   return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
   return y(d.y);
  })
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('fill', function(d) {
   return d.color;
  });

var lines = canvas.selectAll('line')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr('x1', function(d) {
   return x(d.lines[0].x1);
  })
  .attr('y1', function(d) {
   return y(d.lines[0].y1);
  })
  .attr('x2', function(d) {
   return x(d.lines[0].x2);
  })
  .attr('y2', function(d) {
   return y(d.lines[0].y2);
  })
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1);

//initializes circles at center to begin
render();

d3.timer(function() {
 //Update FPS
 var now = Date.now(), duration = now - start;
 text.text(~~(++frames * 1000 / duration));
 if (duration >= 1000) frames = 0, start = now;

 if (run) {
  rendezvous();
  render();
 }
});

function render() {
 circles.attr('transform', function(d) {
  return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
 }).attr('fill', function(d) {
  return d.color;
 });
    //Transform the line here???
   if(run){
  lines.attr('x1', function(d) {
   return +(d3.select(this).attr("x1")) + d.vx;
  })
  .attr('y1', function(d) {
   return +(d3.select(this).attr("y1")) + d.vy;
  })
 }
}


function rendezvous() {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.vx += (Math.random()-0.5)*0.5;
  d.vy += (Math.random()-0.5)*0.5;
  d.x += d.vx;
  d.y += d.vy;

  d.lines[0].x1 = d.x;
  d.lines[0].y1 = d.y;
  d.lines[0].x2 = 0;
  d.lines[0].y2 = 0;
 });
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: rgb(39, 40, 34);
 position: absolute;
}

h1 {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 color: white;
}

#fps {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 fill: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body id = "body">
  <h1>Swarm Demo: </h1>
  <button type="button"onclick = "play();">Play/Pause</button>
 </body>
 <script src="js/rendezvous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is tremendously helpful - what makes this non ideal, and what could I do to refactor my code in a more "D3" way?

Comment: I reckon that the problem is consistency: sometimes you use the linear scale, sometimes you don't. If you refactor your code, you could use the same value for the circles' cx and cy and the lines' x1 and y1.

Comment: Why did you include a `+` before the return?

Comment: Because `attr` as a getter returns a string. That + is to turn the string into a number.